# ExecuteScalar() with a parameter not working

Tags: ado.net

This always returns an error at `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` telling me that `The parameterized query '(@Name nvarchar(4000))select count(*) from Locations where name=' expects the parameter '@Name', which was not supplied.`

What have I done wrong? **location** is a string.

```
        int count = 0;
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Locations where name=@Name", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",location);

            conn.Open();
            count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Is `location` variable set? Maybe a null value is causing the exception?

Comment: definately not, `string location = profile.Location==null?"":profile.Location;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use like this it helps you....

```
int count = 0;
        using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Locations where name=@Name", conn);


                SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) { Value = "Avinash" };
                command.Parameters.Add(paramName);

            conn.Open();
            count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify the command type. Should be something like:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Locations where name=@Name", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",location);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        conn.Open();
        count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        conn.Close();
    }
```